# Pipe is not recognised when in a multi-character delimiter

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, delimiter, separator

I have a file delimited with `|;|`.
Example;

```
1|;|2|;|3|;|4|;|5
1|;|2|;|3|;|4|;|5
```

I need to change the delimiter to `:` or something else,

but `FS` in `awk` does not do anything to pipes `|`

```
awk '$1=$1' FS="|;|" OFS=":" file

1|:|2|:|3|:|4|:|5
1|:|2|:|3|:|4|:|5
```

pipe `|` is recognized when used as a single character separator;

```
awk '$1=$1' FS="|" OFS="" file

1:2:3:4:5
1:2:3:4:5
```

however, `sed` resolves the issue,

```
sed 's/|;|/:/g' file
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to do with `awk` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FS contains a regular expression, `|` mean *alternative* in regular expressions. Backslash the pipes to match them literally:

```
awk '$1=$1' FS='\\|;\\|' OFS=:
```

The reason while a single pipe works is one-character FS is treated specially:

> If FS is a  single  character,  fields are  separated  by that character.  If FS is the null string, then each individual character becomes a separate field.  Otherwise, FS is expected to be a full  regular  expression.   In the special case that FS is a single space, fields are separated by runs of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines.